# Select2 and Ajax loading, search but I can't choose result in Yii2 framework

Tags: ajax, yii2, jquery-select2

I'm using: Select2 and Ajax loading from tutorial: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-ajax.

I have a problem, the script works but I can't choose a value. I can search but I want to choose from the results. I click one and nothing happens, value doesn't get to input.

Form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'top_surname_surname_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'initValueText' => $cityDesc, // set the initial display text
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Wpisz nazwisko'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => $url,
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(top_surname_surname_id) { return top_surname_surname_id.text; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (top_surname_surname_id) { return top_surname_surname_id.text; }'),
    ],
]);?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionSurnamelist($q = null, $id = null) {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '']];
    if (!is_null($q)) {
        $query = new Query;
        $query->select('surname_id, surname_name AS text')
            ->from('surname')
            ->where(['like', 'surname_name', $q])
            ->limit(20);
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        $out['results'] = array_values($data);
    }
    elseif ($id > 0) {
        $out['results'] = ['id' => $id, 'text' => Surname::find($id)->surname_name];
    }
    return $out;
}
```

The problem was in this line:

```
$query->select('surname_id, surname_name AS text')
    ->from('surname')
    ->where(['like', 'surname_name', $q])
    ->limit(20);
```

Work then I edit code to:

```
$query->select('surname_id AS id, surname_name AS text')
    ->from('surname')
    ->where(['like', 'surname_name', $q])
    ->limit(20);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you correctly.your result should be something like

```
$out['results'] = [
    'id' => your_id,
    'text' => some text,
];
```

but if you see your if condition  you are selecting `surname_id` which is not same as `id` so either use alias or use foreach loop to your `$data` e.g

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $out['results'] = [
        'id' => $value->surname_id,
        'text' => $value->text,
    ]; 
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found problem in my code. I edit my first post with good code. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the id to redirect select to the fields.